# Electric wiring in a kitchen island

Tags: electrical, wiring

My contractor installed wires for an extra outlet in my kitchen island that I do not want.  Can I just leave that wire in the cabinet and not install the outlet?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Code requires one outlet If memory serves but my code books are at work.

Comment: Code would likely require a device attached to the exposed wire in question.

Comment: @Barbara as one person mentioned EXTRA - does that truly mean an additional outlet in the Island so you have 2 or more or does that mean it is extra in the Kitchen that you don't want ? Very important as it has been mentioned that code requires AT LEAST one (maybe even a GFCI outlet) - and depending on the length of that island might be more than one required. So please also post the size of the island along with the details as to the term 'extra' as you define that - just so we are on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your jurisdiction and building permit, you may be obliged to install an outlet.

If you're legally permitted to not have one, then just cap the wires in a closed approved junction box that is 'accessible' within the cabinet. (I put accessible in quotes because it doesn't have to be really easy to get to... just don't put it somewhere -- like underneath the toekick -- that requires actual disassembly for access.)

Do the future you a favor and don't cut the wire back.

Comment: The fact that some jurisdictions require an outlet is a good hint that you should want one, required or not. Someday someone will likely want to use an appliance on that island, run an extension to the nearest outlet, trip on it, and spill the frying oil on the oven.

Comment: Just because you are required to have a receptacle there, does not oblige you to turn on the circuit breaker.

Answer (score -2):

Although I agree with Jeffery, I see no reason to install the outlet if you don't want it. (When you say extra I'm assuming you now have one) If you don't use the wire as intended however, you are obligated to safe it up properly.  At a minimum clip the ends of the wires of the cable at different lengths, tape them individually then as a group; a box would be nice but could be optional.

Comment: The answer is not code compliant.